# setting a text to a date in future with AfterUpdate for another event

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a form that has a couple of text fields with date entries and I want the afterupdate of one text to update the value of another text field to a date that is 10 years after the date updated in the first text field. I know that I have to use AfterUpdate event for the first field, but I'm not sure how to manipulate date values in VB. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DateAdd Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dateadd-function-HA001228810.aspx).  Here is an example from the Access Immediate window.

```vb
? DateAdd("yyyy", 10, #2013-10-7#)
10/7/2023
```

Comment: So can in the AfterUpdate of field 1 I can put:
field1 = DateAdd (yyyy, 10, field2) ?

Comment: I think it may work if you add quotes around `yyyy` as in my example.  Try it.  If you get an error, add the code to your question, indicate which line triggers the error, and give us the full text of the error message.